# What's the use of plane in this example

Tags: three.js

I was looking at demo by Mrdoob on dragging cubes.

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html

I have understood the basic code to add cubes and some other basic functionality. But i'm not getting what for? PLANE has been used in the code. I am understanding its being used obviously for dragging the cubes somehow, but why hasn't object's TRANSLATION property been used here?

[view-source:http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html](http://view-source:http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html)

And why are we subtracting the **PLANE** position from **offset** and then **offset** from **intersects[ 0 ].point**

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the plane is being used as something for a ray to intersect, in order to get a position to work with in the scene.  If there were nothing to intersect the ray with, there wouldn't be any reliable way to know what the mouse is pointing at.

Comment: Why are we subtracting the PLANE position from offset and then offset from intersects[ 0 ].point ?